# Selenium in Python doesn't recognise changes in the DOM even after waiting

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm using selenium on a **Python** script to get some data and execute some scripts on a javascript/ajax rendered website, which means some buttons or scripts will change the DOM without loading a new page or changing the URL.

The situation is: as soon as the page is loaded, I execute the following script:

```
driver1.execute_script("javascript:changeOption('a', 'b','otherPage.html');")
```

changeOption is a script written directly inside the script tags of the HTML. It works, and the script will cause the DOM to change.

Now, the DOM has changed and there are new scripts written directly on the HTML, which I can clearly see inside Chrome's inspector "Elements" tab. I wait some seconds and try to run one of the new scripts:

```
driver1.execute_script("javascript:filterOption(0);")
```

And I get an error! It says this script 'filterOption' doesn't exist.

After some investigation, I notice selenium isn't recognising that the DOM has changed and that there are new elements and scripts inside the page! That's why it says the new script doesn't exist.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Implicit and explicit waits. Neither worked.
- time.sleep(), with several seconds, before executing the second script. Didn't work either.
- Forcibly try to execute the script with "try...except" statement inside a while loop. Never works, always goes to the exception.
- Checked whether the page selenium is 'seeing' is the updated page, by executing again the first script, checking for some elements, waiting for new elements to appear etc. No, it isn't: selenium really hasn't noticed the DOM was updated, **that's for sure**.

I did some research here and on the documentation looking for some way to force selenium to read the DOM again without refreshing the page, because refreshing would cause it to go back to the very first page and lose all the changes. It looks like there is no way to do it and every single answer I found was different and didn't work.

Do you have any suggestions of what I could do so Selenium will notice there are new scripts on the DOM?

Thank you!

P.S: I'm using the latest selenium with Python 3 and Chrome.

Comment: Both 'changeOption' and 'filterOption' are functions (not methods) that are to be called by the HTML when a button is pressed, so they don't run unless called. Also, Selenium was able to call the first, but it was not able to call the latter because Selenium hasn't notice the page has changed and the script is now there. It also won't recognise new buttons, elements and other stuff.

Comment: I associate this to a current window handler issue. Take a look at the output of  `print(driver.window_handles)` before and after the `changeOption` call. If the output differs, you can use `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])` where 1 is assumed to be the last element in the list. (Just a suggestion)

Comment: @slackmart, it returns the same list containing the same single element before and after.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

It turns out the new code is rendered inside an iFrame, that's why selenium couldn't see it before.